# Could not start a new session -Unreachable browser exception when running appium

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'RAJESHRJ97', ip: '169.254.244.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:566)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at Base.main(Base.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.getHost(ApacheHttpClient.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    ... 10 more

Comment: please provide some more info, running code, example script for running appium. Anything that might help, and please extend it in question.

Comment: Hope this answer fix your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515083/8918302